# Regarding Security in Hadoop 1.0.0 release

Tags: security, hadoop

Hadoop 1.0.0 is released in dec 2011. And its in Beta version.

As per the below link security feature•Security (strong authentication via Kerberos authentication protocol) is added in hadoop 1.0.0 release.
http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/01/apache-hadoop-1.0.0

But we didnt find any documentation related to this in 1.0.0 documentation.

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/

Is there any documentation reg security feature available in 1.0.0 release and how to configure and use the same. Any inputs on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
MRK

Comment: Maybe ask Hadoop on their mailing-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any documentation reg security feature available in 1.0.0 release and how to configure and use the same. Any inputs on this is greatly appreciated.

Hadoop Security documentation is some what sparse, Cloudera has the most exhaustive [documentation](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Security+Guide) for CDH3. It should be more or less applicable for Hadoop 1.0.0 also.

This [link](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoopsecurity.html) has consolidated information about articles/documentation about Hadoop Security.

> As per the below link security feature•Security (strong authentication via Kerberos authentication protocol) is added in hadoop 1.0.0 release. http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/01/apache-hadoop-1.0.0

BTW, Hadoop 1.0.0 is branding of 0.20.205 which had been in production for quite some time. There will also be Apache Hadoop 2.0.0 and 3.0.0 releases. Also, Hadoop 0.23 cut will also have the security features implemented and it also has the next generation MR architecture (MRv2).

Comment: I also find the example on setting up HTTP SPNEGO authentication for the Web consoles in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133256/hadoop-web-authentication-using-kerberos/8142340#8142340 very useful.

Comment: Hi, Am using apache hadoop 1.0.0 version. Could you please point me doc to configure kerberos authetication with hadoop. CDH docmentation seems related to their release. ( I mean config files anbd all).. I would like to see general documentation which i can use with apache hadoop. Please let me know if there any documetationb abt kerberos protocol and how to configure the same to use with hadoop.

Comment: `CDH docmentation seems related to their release.` - could you point me to the difference? CDH is based on Apache, AFAIK there shouldn't be much difference. Cloudera documentation is the closest I could get for configuring Kerberos in Hadoop.