# Setting up Kerberos on HDP 2.1

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, distributed-computing

I have 2 node Ambari Hadoop cluster running on CentOS 6. Recently I setup Kerberos for the services in the cluster as per the instructions detailed here:
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.0.0/bk_ambari_security/content/ambari-kerb.html

In addition to the above documentation, found that you have to add additional configurations for the Web Namenode UI and so on (QuickLinks in the Ambari server console for each of the Hadoop Services) to work. Hence I followed the configuration options, listed in the question portion of the article to setup HTTP Authentication:[Hadoop Web Authentication using Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133256/hadoop-web-authentication-using-kerberos)

Also to create the secret http file, I used the command to generate the file on node 1, and then copied the file to the same folder location on node 2 on the cluster as well:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/security/keytabs/http_secret bs=1024 count=1
```

Updated the Zookeeper JAAS client file under,  `/etc/zookeeper/conf/zookeeper_client_jaas.conf` to add the following:

```
Client { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
useKeyTab=false 
useTicketCache=true 
keyTab='/etc/security/keytabs/zk.service.keytab' 
principal='zookeeper/host@realm-name'; 
};
```

This step followed from the article: http://blog.spryinc.com/2014/03/configuring-kerberos-security-in.html

When I restarted my Hadoop services, I get the `401 Authentication Required` error, when I try to access the NameNode UI/ NameNode Logs/ NameNode JMX and so on. None of the links given in the QuickLinks drop down is able to connect and pull up the data.

Any thoughts to resolve this error?

Comment: Anyone can help with the above question?